# Rails routes for self nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

In my rails app I have a Task model.
In my app, my tasks can have substasks and so on. Since my subtasks are tasks with only a parent task, I did a self-nested model such as

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## Self Join
  has_many :subtasks, class_name: "Task",
  foreign_key: "parent_task_id"

  belongs_to :parent_task, class_name: "Task"
  ##
end
```

I have now a trouble making routes for this model.

I naively thought that it would be that simple. Here it is:

```
resources :tasks do
  resources :tasks
end
```

The result I try to acheive is by going to this url : "/tasks/1/tasks" is that I can render (by the way, in all my controllers I curently render in JSON not using views) the tasks that have as parent_task_id 1.

Hope you understand my request.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Can you add the contents of your routes file (just the part which talks about tasks) to your question please?  Since your question is about routing we need to see what you have already.

Comment: as far as i can understand you need something like this resources :task do
   resources :task
   resources :parent_task
   resources :subtasks
end

Comment: here is a good rails cast on it:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: @Yas My tasks can have an infinite layer of subtasks. Like task1 : parent = nul - task2 : parent = task1 - task3 : parent = task2. And so on.